# Git doesn't save created branches

Tags: git

I've introduced the following commands in git bash:

`git init`

`git checkout -b master`  (master appears as "checkouted" by default, but it lets me executing this command).

`git checkout -b branch1`

`git checkout master`

And gives me the following error:

`error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

It lets me to create branches with the same name as much as I want. It seems that it's forgetting the branches I'm creating...

Comment: What does `git branch -vv` say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no commits on your master, so it's not referenced.

You should do the following:

```
git init

// Create a file to add
git touch README.md

// Add this file to the stage
git add README.md

// Do your first commit.
git commit "Initial commit"

// Create a new branch and check it out
git checkout -b new-branch
```

Then, checkout of the master will work

```
git checkout master
```

(BTW, it's useless to do `git checkout -b master` as this branch is created and checked out when you do `git init`)